# Toast not showing propertly in activity before read .txt file. Android

Tags: android

Need help!

I try to show toast message(msg: please wait...) then something happend (loading loading/reading .txt file) and then another toast (msg: done!).

But first toast don't show.. or maybe it is too quiclky
Loading this .txt file takes some time (~5sec) i want to inform user about it.

Any ideas? I alredy tried sleep and other...

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
...
...
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Thanks in advance !

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you running the file access asynchronously? if not, you should never run long, blocking operations in the main thread. it's probably unable to render your first toast until after the file access is done, at which point it should have already disappeared. try the access in an `AsyncTask`.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        [access/mess around with the file]
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please place the loading process int a new Thread,I think the main process is blocked.

Comment: Yes, propably you are rigth but it is sooooo complicated. I needed simply and quick solution of this problem. Thanks ;)